# Как добавить неблокирующий таймер для sherrypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy

Как добавить к серверу cherrypy независимую неблокирующую сервер функцию, например

```
def foo_every_sec()
   print(time.time())
```

периодически, например, каждую секунду, вызываемую таймером? Повторюсь, желательно чтобы на время работы таймера и функции не блокировалась работа сервера, и минимизировать, а лучше избежать снижения его производительности.
Сервер

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на модуль "Threading". 
http://python-3.ru/page/import-threading Если нужно сделать именно таймер:
https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-threading-python/klass-timer-modulja-threading/

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил и именно с параллельным потоком, плюс повесил на него интерфейс Tkinter, там и таймер есть after. Скоро опубликую готовое решение.
Жаль что не получилось решить c Async, похоже loop sherrypy не прерывается...

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение, сервер (классический sherrypy + ws4py) вынесен в отдельный модуль websoct. daemon=False корректнее завершает потоки в данном случае. На Tkinter можно повесить контроль и управление сервером и прочий интерфейс. Все работает хорошо.

```
import time, threading, cherrypy
from tkinter import *

def server():
    import websoct

def sender():
    global aft
    cherrypy.engine.publish('websocket-broadcast', str(int(time.time())))
    aft = root.after(1000,sender)

def on_closing():
    root.after_cancel(aft)
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
    root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk();
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",on_closing)
    aft = root.after(1000, sender)
    t = threading.Thread(target=server, name="My Server", daemon=False)
    t.start()
    root.mainloop()
    t.join()
```